How to program Grover's Operator?
I understand the theory behind Grover's operator but I still am unsure how to code it. I have a quantum circuit with 13 qubits. Could someone please tell me step by step the code to use for Grover's operator? Thanks.

Grover's diffusion operator given by the following unitary:
$$ U_s = 2 |s\rangle \langle s| - I, $$
where $|s\rangle$ is the equal superposition state, which can be generated from the all-zeros states by applying $H$ gates to each qubit:
$$ |s\rangle = H^{\otimes n} |0\rangle^{\otimes n} $$
So, replacing $|s\rangle$ (and $\langle s |$) in the operator expression, you get:
$$ U_s = 2 \, H |0\rangle  \langle 0| H - I,$$
where I have omitted the $^{\otimes n}$ superscript for the $H$ gates (and all-zeros state) for convenience.
Now, since $HH = I$, we can sandwich the identity in the expression above without changing the result:
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_s &= 2 \, H |0\rangle  \langle 0| H - H \, I \, H
\\
\\
U_s &= H \left ( 2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I \right) H
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, consider the matrix representation of the expression in between the $H$ gates above:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = & \, \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = -1 & \, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{aligned}
$$
This last matrix corresponds to a gate that inverts the phase of the all-zeros state, and the pre-factor of −1 is simply associated with a global phase we can ignore. To construct this gate, you can first flip all bits with an $X$ gate, apply a multi-controlled $Z$ gate on all qubits $MCZ$, and then flip the bits back with another $X$:
$$2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = X \, \text{MC}Z \, X .$$
Replacing in $U_s$, you get the following sequence of gates:
$$U_s = H \, X \, \text{MC}Z \, X \, H,$$
where, again, all of these are being applied to all qubits.
You can construct the $MCZ$ gate with a $MCX$ where you apply $H$ gates before and after the target qubit (since $Z = HXH$)
Below is an example of how to implement this circuit in qiskit:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

n = 13 # number of qubits

qc = QuantumCircuit(n, name=' $U_s$')

qc.h(range(n))
qc.x(range(n))
qc.barrier()
qc.h(0)
qc.mcx(list(range(1,n)),0)
qc.h(0)
qc.barrier()
qc.x(range(n))
qc.h(range(n))

If you draw the circuit above for 3 qubits, this is what you will see:

